# Typing route in js LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: javascript, laravel

i've a problem by typing route in js

```
          $('.findInfo').append("<a href="+"{{route('peopleAccount',['user_id'\=\>"+msg['user_id'][i]+"])}}"+"><li>"+msg['user_name'][i]+"</li></a>");
```

the problem is that html row is:

```
<a href="{{route('peopleAccount',['user_id'=">1])}}&gt;<li>Orest</li></a>
```

but should be

```
  <a href="{{route('peopleAccount',['user_id'=>1])}}<li>Orest</li></a>
```

Help me, please!!!

Comment: Maybe the symbol => is not allowed

Comment: Is that code in a .js file or a .blade.php file?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix php and js which won't work. The real issue here is not your correct link generation, rather you trying to generate links to a php method which would only run once on page load. You can do something like this.

```
$('.findInfo').append('<a href="{{ url('/peopleaccount/') }}' + msg['user_id'][i] + '"><li>' + msg['user_name'][i] + '</li></a>>');
```

Edit : Since you need to fetch the parameter passed in the controller, do this.

```
public function getPeopleAccount($user_id)
{
    return $user_id;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i now take this var

Comment: Route::get('/peopleaccount/{post_id'},[
        'uses'  =>  'UserController@getPeopleAccount',
        'as'    =>  'peopleAccount'
    ]);

Comment: public function getPeopleAccount(Request $request)
    {
        return $request['post_id'];
    }

Comment: I've updated my code to use url method to generate full link. Try  using that. If you need further help post your complete js code to check.

Comment: Everything is good, route works, but how can i now take my war user_id

Comment: there was a little mistake
 
public function getPeopleAccount(Request $request) { return $request['user_id']; } but anyway it does'nt work

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can directly get the parameter passed in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works thank you very much my Controllerfunction code

```
public function getPeopleAccount(Request $request,$user_id)
    {
        return $user_id;
    }
```